# Allowing the user to pick a color and storing it for later use

Tags: c#, console

I'm writing a console application where one of the things I want to implement is letting the user pick the color they want to represent them and then using it throughout the program.

My idea was to have a menu that works through a switch statement (seen below), that part is easy enough, but how can I go on and invoke the color they choose in this switch later in the program?

```
private static void colorSelector()
    {
        var myKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
        switch (myKey.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.F1:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F2:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F3:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F4:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F5:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F6:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                break;
        }
```

I hope I'm making myself clear enough here, I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks.

Comment: This is a fine question for a different setting, but it's not really the kind of question that StackOverflow was created to answer. Please see the [How to Ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You are reinventing a wheel, this is already supported.  With the console window displayed, press Alt+Space, Properties, Color tab.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of assigning it directly to `Console.ForegroundColor`, use a variable instead and use that later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable like this

```
ConsoleColore color;
```

Then save your color in it like this

```
color = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

after that you can use it in your program!

Answer (score 0):

you can assign it to a class level variable and then retrieve it throughout you class:

```
class Program
{
    private static ConsoleColor _userColor;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var myKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
        switch (myKey.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.F1:
                _userColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F2:
                _userColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F3:
                _userColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F4:
                _userColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F5:
                _userColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.F6:
                _userColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                break;

        }

        DoSomething();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = _userColor;
        Console.WriteLine("color choosen");

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.BackgroundColor = _userColor;
        Console.WriteLine("flipped it");

    }
}
```